# Network usage application indicator

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, indicator

I need a application indicator to show what is the current download and upload network speed. It should be written in text in the panel itself. Like "up:0.5 MBps down:1 MBps". Is there any application indicator to do that or is there an easy way to make one myself?

Digvijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are with all available indicators: [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)
[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/89889/32230) seems to be the nearest to your need.